# Using Closure Stylesheets with Plovr in serve mode

Tags: google-closure-library, plovr

i am using [plovr](http://plovr.com/) for developing a [closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/) application. and that i am often using plovr in serve mode. from this [source code](https://code.google.com/p/plovr/source/browse/src/org/plovr/ConfigOption.java) of plovr and [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plovr/2amxkQXvMso) from the author it seems that plovr also supports compiling closure stylesheets (gss).

with that in mind, i am specifying the bare minimum in my plovr config file to get this working. but can't figure out what url i should use in my page to load the compiled css.

for example, while plovr is running the compiled js can be fetched with

```
http://localhost:9810/compile?id=project_id
```

i guess fetching the compiled css can be done with something like the following:

```
http://localhost:9810/view?id=project_id&name=output.css
```

but unfortunately can't figure out the right documentation for it. what is the approach to achieve this?

also is it possible to make use of the [css class name renaming](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/#Renaming) feature through plovr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://localhost:9810/css/project_id/
```

did the trick. looks like i need not specify the output css file name.